# Usefulness of Empty Parameters

Tags: python-2.7, parameters

Why using empty parameters is useful and when you need them?

EDIT

like in this code to make a Caesar cipher,

```
def main():
  msgRaw = input('Please enter your message: ')
  key = eval(input('Key value: ')

  tempS = ''
  tempL = []

  for i in msgRaw.split():
    for c in i:
      tempS = tempS+chr(ord(c)+key)
    tempL.append(tempS)
    tempS = ''
  print('\nYour encrypted message is: '+' '.join(tempL)+'.')
main()
```

why was tempS and tempL set empty?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Give an example atleast

Comment: What do you mean by empty parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You don't call t hem parameters but the reason they are empty is that in Python you do not declare variables like

int i; 
   or double d;

so what you do is you initialize it empty which would give the interpreter, the knowledge about the the data type of the variable which you can use later

Remember: You cant use variable of one data-type to assign different types of data though.